# TalkBack screen reading issues

Tags: javascript, android, html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to grasp how to code with screen readers in mind, and I'm having a number of issues. The first example is a single HTML element that I tried to display:

```
<h2><span>This is an element.</span></h2>
```

Talkback on Android will read it as "This is an element header 2," but I'd like to know how to make it so that it is just read back as "This is an element."

Another issue is in elements with numerous nested child elements; for example, I tested this:

```
<div aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" tabindex="0">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>This is text for the div.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p> This is additional text. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the screen reader to say "This is text for the div. This is additional text.", but it only says "This is text for the div." I was under the impression that aria-atomic would make it so that all of the contents of the region are read, so what might I be doing wrong? I tried to make the second sentence a title, but that didn't work, either (How would I make it so that both the contents of the div and the title attribute are read in a scenario such as this?).

Finally, while that problem persists, I was weirdly able to get both title text and the content text to be read together with:

```
<a title="for the title">this is additional text</a>
```

...but only when I focus on that element individually. If I tried making that a child of a div with other text, a la:

```
<div>This is a title and <a title="for the title">this is additional text</a></div>
```

It will read off "This is a title and this is additional text," when I want "This is a title and this is additional text for the title." It basically skips the title attribute.

This is very confusing; I've read up on aria attributes and how certain screen readers and Talkback in particular work, but I'm having no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting a span under heading tags like  in your case, screen reader will read the heading level. If you don't want the heading to be read, then do not put the span inside heading tag.